# Security, exposed ip address in GitHub

Tags: security, github, ip-address

I would like to use Github to save and share my work.
My main concern is security. Because Github is open source, i am worried that someone could potentially mess with my project.

I am not saving any passwords in the project. I do have a get and post request to an external database.

My ip address is exposed though. Could this be a potential security risk for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am no security expert, but your IP is already exposed if it's to be of any use. You may conceivably draw attention to it, but... just follow standard security precautions and you'll probably be fine.

Comment: Why is your ip address exposed and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to hide your IP, you can probably use `git` and browse GitHub through a proxy or a VPN.

GitHub is just a website and a server to sync your `git` repository to. GitHub **is not open source**.

The fact that the `git` command-line tool and protocol are open source doesn't affect what information GitHub chooses to collect about you.